# Quieting a loud HVAC blower and static pressure concerns

Tags: hvac, sound-proofing, blower

I recently moved into a ~1200 sq ft third-floor condo where the blower setup is off of a closet in the living room. The only return (20"x20") faces the living room area. If you open the return, you can see the blower motor/squirrel cage fan just about a foot away. In other words, there is basically direct line of sight from the fan into the living room and almost no return length. The system is thus very loud; I measured ~70 db+ a few feet away. It also seems like the system might be too powerful for the apartment. For example, it will heat up from 62 to 70 in about 45 mins, even when it's around 32 outside.

Regardless, I've been looking at ways into mitigating the noise. One idea I had was to use something like a cross-talk silencer found here: https://www.priceindustries.com/noisecontrol/products/xt-cross-talk-silencer. This would block the direct line of sight to the fan and also absorb some of the sound.

I made a prototype out of cardboard just to see what would happen. Well, the sound dropped from 70 db down to around 62 db. It's still loud, but much more manageable. Also, the frequency changed and now the sound is far less annoying/turbulent. It sounds more like whooshing air rather than a jet engine. Therefore, I would like to make a more permanent fixture, say out of sheet metal. However, before I go further down this route, I want to better understand possible pitfalls.

I used an anemometer to check the air speed out of one of the supply vents. The air speed drops by about 10-15% with the contraption in the return duct. I've done a lot of reading about this, and I understand that too much static pressure can be a concern because it can shorten the life of the system (among other things). I would like to understand if this much of a reduction in air speed is truly a concern. Does this mean I might have to replace the unit 10-15% sooner than I would otherwise? Is there anything dangerous about this? Do I need to take more measurements and do more calculations to understand if I'm within the static pressure and CFM tolerances of the unit?

I'm also open to other ideas. For example, it might be possible to re-route the return and extend it. Thanks in advance.

Pictures for reference: https://imgur.com/a/8jYbg4t